# Java: Using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public String toMilitary()
{
       return String.format("%2d:%2d:%2d", hour, minute, second);

}
```

This code gives the following error:

> The method `format(String, Object[])` in the type `String` is not applicable for the arguments `(String, int, int, int)`

Also, Enhanced for loop and Variable Parameters shown errors.

Is there a problem with my compiler. Should I re-install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No (unless you seriously have an old compiler), go to your project `Properties` (right click), go to `Java Compiler` and set the `Compiler compliance level` to anything greater than 1.5